# Aws PHP Sdk 3: S3::putObject(): AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 's3.Ireland.amazonaws.com'

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to an S3 bucket using the version 3 of the SDK, but I receive the following error:

> Error executing "PutObject" on
>   "https://s3.Ireland.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/testFile.jpg"; AWS HTTP
>   error: cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 's3.Ireland.amazonaws.com'
>   (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

This is the first time I try to do this, so I'm not much confident.

**Uploading a file through the AWS interface, its URL is something like `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/testFileThroughWeb.jpg`.
So, it seems to be different from the one created by the AWS SDK to PUT the file (that is `https://s3.Ireland.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/testFile.jpg`)**

**Another thing I'd like to point out is the version I pass to the constructor of S3Client.
Its instance is created passing to it the value `stable` for the key `version` while in the bucket policy I use `version: "2012-10-17"`.**

This is the configuration of the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

To save the image in the bucket, I use this code:

```
public function testS3Action()
{
    $fileToUpload = 'http://example.com/an/image.jpg';

    // Get the remote file extension
    $remoteImageExtension = explode('.', $fileToUpload);
    $remoteImageExtension = array_pop($remoteImageExtension);
    $fs = new Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem();
    $tempImage = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'image.') . '.' . $remoteImageExtension;

    /**
     * From the Symfony container
     * @var GuzzleHttp\Client $client
     */
    $client = $this->get('guzzle.client');

    // Get and save file
    $client->get($fileToUpload, ['save_to' => $tempImage]);

    $tempImage = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File($tempImage);

    /**
     * From the Symfony container
     * @var Aws\S3\S3Client $s3
     */
    $s3 = $this->get('shq.amazon.s3');

    $params = [
        'Bucket' => $this->getParameter('amazon.s3.bucket'),
        'Key'    => 'testFile.jpg',
        'Body'   => $tempImage
    ];

    $result = $s3->putObject($params);

    return $result;
}
```

**Which could be the cause of the error I'm getting? Why the host `https://s3.Ireland.amazonaws.com` guessed by the S3Client isn't correct?**

Comment: The SDK shouldn't be "guessing" that value, because it's definitely invalid.  There's no such endpoint as `s3.Ireland...`.  You don't have something, somewhere, in your configuration or code where "Ireland" appears?

Comment: I set it for the region parameter. When I instantiate the S3 client I pass it the value "Ireland" as region param.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such AWS region as "Ireland". The valid regions for S3 are listed [on Amazon's web site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region); the one you're probably trying to use here is EU (Ireland), which would be represented in a region parameter as `eu-west-1`.

Comment: For London region is "eu-west-2"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its late for you, but its new for others:

*AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 's3.Ireland.amazonaws.com' (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)* error's meaning is that you have an error at your S3 URL / configuration. The service can't connect to S3 with your URL conf.

Such as my mistake, today I faced same error because of missing out a URL block.

In addition to this, if you use an alternative DC; that uses AWS platform on their side. You should ask them their own conf settings.